# sqlite database connectivity in servlet

Tags: sqlite, servlets, jdbc

I am writing `jdbc` code in Servlet
But I am getting an error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

I have included a `sqlitejdbc-v056.jar` file
Still I am getting an error.

If i write the same code in separate java file and run it as a java application,
it works properly but it is not working on server

p.s.- I am using Weblogic server.

Comment: I have the same issue. Any luck?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution on my problem.
We have to add the .jar file in lib folder in WEB-INF folder in our workspace
-"Workspace/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/"

Also we need to include it in 'plugins' folder of eclipse.
-"eclipse/plugins/"